# Why do the target-specific function declarations in GCC source use K&R style instead of prototypes?

Tags: function, gcc, declaration, kernighan-and-ritchie

I've been studying the GCC source code and I noticed that most (if not all) target-specific source code files (like arm.c for example) use the old K&R function style.

Is there any particular reason for this? Backward compatibility? Portability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So that you can compile gcc on a system with non-GNU, and potentially really old, compiler, to just get a better compiler on this very system.

Comment: I think that recent versions of gcc require at least C89 (commonly called "ANSI") compliance in the host compiler, but it's likely that the code just hasn't been updated yet.